# RemoteIpAddress in K8S Cluster is always the ingress IP

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have an ASP.NET Core webapi running in an on-prem bare-metal Kubernetes cluster. There's no external load-balancer, and I'm using NGINX ingress.

I want to get the users' IP address, and am using `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` in the .NET code.

Unfortunately, this is picking up the IP address of the nginx ingress (possibly the controller given the namespace)...

`::ffff:10.244.1.85`

Doing a reverse DNS lookup resolves that to...

`10-244-1-85.ingress-nginx.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local`

After a little bit of Googling, I tried adding `externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"` to my service definition, but that didn't make a difference.

This seems like something that should be really trivial and quite a common requirement. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this question provide a useful answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774846/preserving-remote-client-ip-with-ingress

Comment: Unfortunately that's not making a difference.

Comment: Can you post the configuration of ingress?

Comment: Have you checked the HTTP headers in your web application? The typical solution would be to set X-Forwarded-For in Nginx and use it in the application. If the header is missing use the remote address, if it is present use the value from the header.

Comment: @ewramner I hadn't checked the headers. Just tried it, and the header is there, but it's set to "10.244.1.0" which is internal to the cluster, not my machine's IP address.

Answer (score 4):

First try to get ip from header `X-Forwarded-For` as shown below, if it's null then you can use Connection.RemoteIpAddress. Also make sure your nginx configmap has proxy enabled as per screenshot:
[image]

```
var ip = IPAddress.Parse(_accessor.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-For"].FirstOrDefault());
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip.ToString()))
            {
                ip = _accessor.ActionContext.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4();
            }
```