# HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress returns private address for asp.net core in kubernetes

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, nginx

I have an asp.net core 7.0 api application in a docker container hosted in Kubernetes behind an Nginx ingress controller.

To get the client ip address i'm using

> context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress

for all user requests I get a Private Ip address like '10.244.0.1'

In such instances i'm expecting Public IP address

Comment: Try adding `externalTrafficPolicy: "Local"` to your service definition and also refer to the similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774846/preserving-remote-client-ip-with-ingress) which may help to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure nginx to [forward the `X-Forwarded-For` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0#nginx-configuration). Example:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Then setup the `UseForwardedHeaders` middleware. This middleware will update `HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress` using the `X-Forwarded-For` header value.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// ...
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
        ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseForwardedHeaders();

// ...
```

Check: [Configure ASP.NET Core to work with proxy servers and load balancers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-7.0#forwarded-headers)