# How to read client IP addresses from HTTP requests behind Kubernetes services laravel

Tags: linux, nginx, kubernetes, service, kubectl

I have a kubernetes cluster on premise.

I deploy my laravel application and service using nodePort.

```
idnic@mylaptop:~/$ kubectl get pods -n staging
NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mysite-stg-595799c6cd-2nhfn   1/1     Running   0          40m
mysite-stg-595799c6cd-7jz7l   1/1     Running   0          40m

idnic@mylaptop:~/$ kubectl get service -n staging
NAME            TYPE       CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
mysite-stg   NodePort   10.43.234.209   <none>        80:30111/TCP   41m
```

and I use the NGINX load balancer by creating an upstream:

```
upstream my.site {
    server 192.168.1.5:30111;
    server 192.168.1.4:30111;
    server 192.168.1.3:30111 backup;
    server 192.168.1.2:30111 backup;
}

server {
    server_name my.site;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://my.site;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

In my Laravel application, there is a feature to get client IPs accessing my website, but after moving to kubernetes what was detected was the IP address of the Kubernetes worker not the IP address of the client accessing my website.

[client IP detect IP kubernetes worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cMZj.png)

How do I detect IP clients with my topology above?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32112922/how-to-read-client-ip-addresses-from-http-requests-behind-kubernetes-services

Comment: When I set service.spec.externalTrafficPolicy to Local, Now what is detected is the IP of the nginx load balancer server. Can you help me ? @ArghyaSadhu

Comment: Add x-forwarded-for in nginx